# Pass custom header to /oauth2/token API in spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-authorization-server

I am new to spring oauth service and am trying to pass "user-id" as an additional header to /oauth2/token API and then add it as additional parameter in access token generated with JwtTokenCustomizerConfig.tokenCustomizer()

I am not able to find any classes which can help to pass the headers as all older classes are deprecated and new libraries are unfamiliar. Also could not find a way to pass dynamic value to set in accessToken.

Previous oauth2 libraries, headers were parsed with class

```
HeaderMapRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper

                HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(request);
                requestWrapper.addHeader(OAuth2ServerUtils.USER_ID, userId);
```

And with JwtAccessTokenConverter.enhance(), we could add additional paramerter as :

```
String validUserId = request.getHeader(OAuth2ServerUtils.USER_ID);
                    additionalInfo.put(OAuth2ServerUtils.USER_ID, validUserId);
```

Above oauth libraries are deprecated and currently with new library, I want to pass the userId as header to /oauth2/token API and later include into the JWT token generated. I am able to include static key-value pair with below code with new spring authorization server library:

```
@Configuration
public class JwtTokenCustomizerConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer() {
        return (context) -> {
            if (OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType())) {
                context.getClaims().claims((claims) -> {
                    claims.put("userId", "1234");
                });
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `JwtTokenCustomizerConfig` class the example from the How-to guide? Please provide all the context of your question and any relevant code/configuration you're working with.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I have added details to my question

Comment: I added details to the previous answer. Did that help answer this question? You seem to still be wondering how to include dynamic values in the access token. Or is this just about accessing a header?

Comment: Thanks for your response @SteveRiesenberg I am still confused on how to access a userId header in /oauth2/token api and use it in customrepository suggested. I am fairly new to oauth and java spring

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the current `HttpServletRequest` in Spring using `RequestContextHolder`. For example:

```java
var requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
var request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
var userId = request.getHeader("userId");
```

This would work in the example `OAuth2TokenCustomizer` if the header is passed to the `/oauth2/token` endpoint in the request.